# Hosting service for APNS

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting, apple-push-notifications

Is there any good service for Apple Push Notification Service (APNS)?
I've checked Site5, but I'm not sure if I cant achieve this with hostbasic plan. Will they allow outgoing connections on the ports 2195 and 2196 in order to able to send push notification?
Can anyone confirm this or suggest some better services?

PS (I  also need to support PHP and MySQL).

Comment: What do you mean by APNS hosting?

Comment: @MichaelMior It's an acronym for Apple Push Notification Service.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But what do you mean by APNS hosting? You mean a hosting service which will allow you to communicate with APNS?

Comment: Yes exactly, currently I have my hosting service on fatcow and I can't make my push notification service to work because they don't allow outgoing connection on ports 2195 and 2196 (required by Apple Push notification service). I've updated my question.

Comment: It's an expensive solution, but [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) provides a great service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've purchased hosting plan on site5 (hostbasic) and everything works fine.
Didn't had to ask to open additional ports, 2195 and 2196 seems to be already opened.

Answer (score 0):

1and1.com suffers all the same faults as any other shared hosting provider, but they give you ssh access with the ability to install and compile packages if you ever need to.  There's an admin panel for cronjobs but you can also do it via SSH via crontab. If you're not interested in SSH then I'd go elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I Recently Used the Hosting from [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/) (**Shared Hosting)** , They have the port 2195 open and support push notifications under apns. Its working for me, may be others can get some help too.

**EDIT:**

Current I m using **Shared Hosting from Host Gator** and when i requested, they have **opened the port 2195** (Only **out-bond**) for me and its **working**!!! I can able to send notification. Cheers!!!

Hostgator is **cheaper** than Site5, compare plans [here](http://www.hostgator.com/shared)  and [here](http://www.site5.com/hosting/web/).